# ArangoDb.Net upsert always insert

Tags: arangodb

I'm making a small application with CRUD functions with ArangoDatabase and its driver:

http://www.arangoclient.net/

Here is my code:

```
        var insert = new Account
        {
            Email = "email01@gmail.com",
            FirstName = "Adam",
            LastName = "Smith"
        };

        var update = new Account
        {
            Email = "email01@gmail.com",
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Peterson"
        };

        using (var arangoDatabase = new ArangoDatabase(new DatabaseSharedSetting()
        {
            Url = "http://127.0.0.1:8529/",
            Database = "_system",
            Credential = new NetworkCredential()
            {
                UserName = "root",
                Password = "xvxvc"
            }
        }))
        {
            arangoDatabase.Query()
                .Upsert(_ => new Account() {Email = insert.Email},
                    _ => insert, ((aql, x) => update))
                    .In<Account>()
                    .Execute();
        }
```

For the first time running, [insert] object is added to database.
Therefore, my database now is :

[image: Data has been imported successfully]

But at the second time of running code, it throws me an error :

```
unique constraint violated (while executing). ErrorNumber: 1210 HttpStatusCode: 409
```

The question is: What is my problem and how to solve it?

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem could be upsert search expression serialization:

Assume `Account` class definition is:

```cs
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

upsert search expression: `new Account() {Email = insert.Email}` will serializes to:

`{ Email: "email01@gmail.com", FirstName: null, LastName: null }`

but what is expected is:

`{ Email: "email01@gmail.com" }`

Since search expression will never found a document, then insert will occur and you get `unique constraint violated`.

There are two solution to avoid serializing `FirstName` and `LastName` members:

One is we could use Json.net `JsonProperty` attribute to ignore nulls in serialization:

```cs
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And the other way is to use an anonymous object for search expression:

```cs
arangoDatabase.Query()
                .Upsert(_ => new Account() {Email = insert.Email}

// should be

arangoDatabase.Query()
                .Upsert(_ => new {Email = insert.Email}
```

One note about using anonymous object is that `Email` member could resolve to something else base on what you specify for its naming convention, for example:

```cs
public class Account
{
    [DocumentProperty(Identifier = IdentifierType.Key)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

If you specify `Email` as a Key identifier, then you should use `_key` in the anonymous object:

`arangoDatabase.Query()
                    .Upsert(_ => new { _key = insert.Email }`